# Amount of Rep for Next Privilege Varies

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, mobile-web, android

On the desktop (Google Chrome), the amount of rep needed to create tag synonyms is 2500 rep. But surprisingly, on the mobile-web version, it says you need 3k rep to create tag synonyms. So which one is correct and can we fix the wrong rep number to become correct?

Desktop:

[image]

Mobile-Web (Android, this does not happen on Apple devices):

[image]

**EDIT:** So seemingly, 3k is just the rounded version of 2,500. Can we change 3k to 2.5k? It doesn't really seem to take much space as you can see. And it is more accurate by 500 points.

Comment: It's still 2500, rounded to an integer "k" rep for displaying on that particular page. (Try hovering over "3k".) But it is kind of misleading... perhaps [a few more lines of C#](https://twitter.com/JasonPunyon/status/612007200685338624) are called for.

Comment: @3дравыйСмысл "Try to hover over 3K": that is a little hard on a mobile device.

Comment: `Mobile-Web (Android, this does not happen on Apple devices):` it does (at least on iphone6 with acutal iOS). I posted it on meta.SO as I'm normaly not active on meta.SE and didn't find anything in meta.SO search results.

Comment: Mmm...just use the Android app instead?